# Laravel - Dynamic relationship using hasManyThough() and unique merge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I can think of several ad-hoc ways to do this, but I'm really looking for a 'best practices' type of solution.

**I have 3 tables involved**

- users (user_id)
- usages ('user_id', 'provider_id', 'nurse_id', 'patient_id')
- usage_alerts ('usage_id')

Im trying to eager load `alerts` using `hasManyThrough()` based on a user's role.

The `user_id` field is agnostic, and can apply to any role, so merging and filtering needs to take place.

Using `$this->hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage')->get()` will return a collection, making the `->merge()` method available.  However, when eager loading, on return, i get an error since it's a collection object.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints()
```

**For example, this is my current relation** (returns the error above)

```
public function alerts() 
{ 

    $alerts = $this->hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage')->get();

    if(Sentry::getUser()->inGroup(Sentry::findGroupByName('provider')))
        $alerts->merge($this->hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage', 'provider_id'));

    if(Sentry::getUser()->inGroup(Sentry::findGroupByName('patient')))
        $alerts->merge($this->hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage', 'patient_id'));

    if(Sentry::getUser()->inGroup(Sentry::findGroupByName('nurse')))
        $alerts->merge($this->hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage', 'nurse_id'));

    return $alerts;

}
```

Any suggestions?
 Pperhaps too much complexity for a relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice manipulates the relationship, though official documentation on how lacks.  For your scenario, you can `union` the additional queries into the primary "agnostic" relationship:

```
$relation = $this->hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage');

foreach (['provider','patient','nurse'] as $group) {
    if (Sentry::getUser()->inGroup(Sentry::findGroupByName($group))) {
        $relation->getBaseQuery()->union(
            $this->
            hasManyThrough('UsageAlert', 'Usage', $group . '_id')->
            getBaseQuery()->
            select('UsageAlert.*') // limits union to common needed columns
        );
    }
}

return $relation;
```

This approach returns a `Relation`, rather than a `Collection`, as would be expected by API users.

Comment: This seems to work when removing `getBaseQuery()` from the first line (otherwise, returns a `Builder` instance), but then i get a `Cardinality violation` as the first `hasManyThrough()` is selecting one additional field (the foreign key in the intermediary table). `(select \`usage_alerts\`.*, \`usages\`.\`user_id\` from \`usage_alerts\` inner join \`usages\` on \`usages\`.\`id\` = \`usage_alerts\`.\`usage_id\` where \`usages\`.\`user_id\` = 2) 
union (select * from \`usage_alerts\` inner join \`usages\` on \`usages\`.\`id\` = \`usage_alerts\`.\`usage_id\` where \`usages\`.\`provider_id\` = 2)`

Comment: Not near a terminal to test, but -- if I'm following -- you can limit the selection in the unioned query.  I've edited my code in response (but again, not near a terminal to test).  (And, aside, I thought one needed the eloquent builder to perform the union against, but true I was returning the builder not the relation. I've updated my code to also account for this.)

Comment: Fantastic!  Adding the `select()` did the trick.  Thanks for your help!