# Custom Laravel Relations?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hypothetical situation: Let's say we have 3 models:

- `User`
- `Role`
- `Permission`

Let's also say `User` has a many-to-many relation with `Role`, and `Role` has a many-to-many relation with `Permission`.

So their models might look something like this. (I kept them brief on purpose.)

```
class User
{
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}

class Role
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
}

class Permission
{
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

**What if you wanted to get all the `Permission`s for a `User`?** There isn't a `BelongsToManyThrough`.

It seems as though you are sort of stuck doing something that doesn't feel quite right and doesn't work with things like `User::with('permissions')` or `User::has('permissions')`.

```
class User
{
    public function permissions() {
        $permissions = [];
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            foreach ($role->permissions as $permission) {
                $permissions = array_merge($permissions, $permission);
            }
        }
        return $permissions;
    }
}
```

This example is, just one example, don't read too much into it. The point is, how can you define a *custom* relationship? Another example could be the relationship between a facebook comment and the author's mother. Weird, I know, but hopefully you get the idea. Custom Relationships. How?

In my mind, a good solution would be for that relationship to be described in a similar way to how describe any other relationship in Laravel. Something that returns an Eloquent `Relation`.

```
class User
{
    public function permissions() {
        return $this->customRelation(Permission::class, ...);
    }
}
```

**Does something like this already exist?**

Comment: Yes, return a relationship, not a materialized array. You may start from an existing relationship and add onto it. [See this example.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25578108/2908724)

Comment: @bishop Interesting! I hadn't thought of manipulating an existing relationship. Laravel needs a "recipes" page in the docs for stuff like this. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The closest thing to a solution was what @biship [posted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577954/laravel-dynamic-relationship-using-hasmanythough-and-unique-merge/25578108#25578108). Where you would manually modify the properties of an existing `Relation`. This might work well in some scenarios. Really, it may be the right solution in some cases. However, I found I was having to strip down all of the `constraints` added by the `Relation` and manually add any new `constraints` I needed.

My thinking is this... If you're going to be stripping down the `constraints` each time so that the `Relation` is just "bare". Why not make a custom `Relation` that doesn't add any `constraints` itself and takes a `Closure` to help facilitate adding `constraints`?

### Solution

Something like this seems to be working well for me. At least, this is the basic concept:

```
class Custom extends Relation
{
    protected $baseConstraints;

    public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, Closure $baseConstraints)
    {
        $this->baseConstraints = $baseConstraints;

        parent::__construct($query, $parent);
    }

    public function addConstraints()
    {
        call_user_func($this->baseConstraints, $this);
    }

    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
    {
        // not implemented yet
    }

    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
    {
        // not implemented yet
    }

    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        // not implemented yet
    }

    public function getResults()
    {
        return $this->get();
    }
}
```

The methods not implemented yet are used for eager loading and must be declared as they are abstract. I haven't that far yet. :)

And a trait to make this new `Custom` Relation easier to use.

```
trait HasCustomRelations
{
    public function custom($related, Closure $baseConstraints)
    {
        $instance = new $related;
        $query = $instance->newQuery();

        return new Custom($query, $this, $baseConstraints);
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
// app/User.php
class User
{
    use HasCustomRelations;

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->custom(Permission::class, function ($relation) {
            $relation->getQuery()
                // join the pivot table for permission and roles
                ->join('permission_role', 'permission_role.permission_id', '=', 'permissions.id')
                // join the pivot table for users and roles
                ->join('role_user', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'permission_role.role_id')
                // for this user
                ->where('role_user.user_id', $this->id);
        });
    }
}

// app/Permission.php
class Permission
{
    use HasCustomRelations;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->custom(User::class, function ($relation) {
            $relation->getQuery()
                // join the pivot table for users and roles
                ->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                // join the pivot table for permission and roles
                ->join('permission_role', 'permission_role.role_id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
                // for this permission
                ->where('permission_role.permission_id', $this->id);
        });
    }
}

You could now do all the normal stuff for relations without having to query in-between relations first.
```

### Github

I went a ahead and put [all this on Github](https://github.com/johnnyfreeman/laravel-custom-relation) just in case there are more people who are interested in something like this. This is still sort of a science experiment in my opinion. But, hey, we can figure this out together. :)

Comment: you need to return the `$models` in the `initRelation` method otherwise `->with('customrelation')` and `->load('customrelation')` won't work, like so:
```
    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation) {
        return $models;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the `hasManyThrough` relationship that Laravel offers?

[Laravel HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

It should help you retrieve all the permissions for a user.

Comment: I have. Actually for my example I believe a `BelongsToManyThrough` would be the ticket, but no such relation exists. That's kind of the point of my post - What do you do when there isn't a stock laravel relation to describe your relationship?

Answer (score -3):

I believe this concept already exists. You may choose on using Laravel ACL Roles and Permissions or Gate, or a package known as Entrust by zizaco.

[Zizaco - Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

[Laracast - watch video 13 and 14](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/16)

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't asking about anything specific to ACL. Just about custom relations. Using Users, Roles, and Permissions was probably misleading. :/