# How do I create a custom relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Is it possible to create custom relationships in Laravel like this,

```
SELECT tasks.* 
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN priorities ON tasks.priority_identifier LIKE CONCAT('%', priorities.identifier)
WHERE priority.id = 10
```

I could use query builder to create this join but how can i return this as a laravel relationship ?

**Edit**

I'm trying to do this without using existing relationship methods(hasMany, hasOne etc)

Comment: [Custom Laravel Relations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213022/custom-laravel-relations) I think this link might help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add conditions to Laravel relations just like any other query builder. I don't know what your relation will look like, but you could do this for example:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class)
        ->where('priority', 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But can I create a completely new relationship method without using existing ones?

Comment: Yes, just rename the function and create as many as you like. :)

Comment: You mean the `tasks()` right ? But i'm talking about this `hasMany()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a custom relationship, unless overriding Eloquent [base class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php).

And add your own.

But you can use Eloquent `scopes` alternative to custom [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes).

Also take a look [here](https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-custom-relation-classes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213022/custom-laravel-relations)