# Eloquent Relationship with multiple many-to-many relationships - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

I have table structures like this :

> jobs
>
> - id
> - name
>
> types
>
> - id
> - name
>
> job_type (pivot table)
>
> - id
> - job_id
> - type_id
>
> tasks
>
> - id
> - description
>
> job_type_task (pivot table)
>
> - id
> - job_type_id
> - task_id

Notes :

1. jobs has many types and vice versa
2. job_type has many tasks and vice versa

**My problem is with this table structures, How can I establish a relationship between 'job' and 'tasks' tables to access all tasks associated with a job?**

I have tried many solution like using hasMany or hasManyThrough but none is working.

Should i change the table stuctures? or any solution to access tasks via job eloquent model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no stock laravel relation for your case as your relation is not direct but through 2 entities and laravel only natively support 1 level down so you can check this package that might help you achieve what you need
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

also there was a similar question that might be similar to your use case that helps creating a new custom relation since the stocked relations is not enough [Custom Laravel Relations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213022/custom-laravel-relations) and also this article explains it nicely https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-custom-relation-classes

here is the implementation of custom relation in case you need it

```php
<?php

namespace App\Relations;

use App\Models\Job;
use App\Models\Task;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class JobTaskRelation extends Relation
{
    /** @var Task|Builder */
    protected $query;

    /** @var Job */
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct(Job $parent)
    {
        parent::__construct(Task::query(), $parent);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addConstraints()
    {
        $this->query->join('job_type_task', 'job_type_task.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
            ->join('job_type', 'job_type.id', '=', 'job_type_task.job_type_id');
        if (static::$constraints) {
            $this->query->where('job_type.job_id', '=', $this->parent->getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
    {
        $this->query
            ->whereIn('job_type.job_id', $this->getKeys($models))
            ->with('jobTypes')
            ->select('tasks.*');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $model->setRelation(
                $relation,
                $this->related->newCollection()
            );
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        $results = $results->unique('id');
        if ($results->isEmpty()) {
            return $models;
        }

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $model->setRelation(
                $relation,
                $results->filter(function (Task $task) use ($model) {
                    return $task->jobTypes->pluck('job_id')->contains($model->id);
                })
            );
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getResults()
    {
        return $this->query->get();
    }
}
```

and now you job model will be something like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Relations\JobTaskRelation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Type');
    }

    public function jobTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\JobType');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return new JobTaskRelation($this);
    }
}
```

and task model will be

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Type');
    }

    public function jobTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\JobType');
    }
}
```

important note to take care of:

since laravel assumes that when we have a model the table is plural and your scheme define the pivot tables as singular it's important that when you define the pivot models to set `$table` to the singular table name and you are good to go

now you can use `Job::find(1)->tasks` or `Job::with('task')->get()`

you might need to add more functions based on what you need in the future and you will need to maintain it

### Using accessor

also another solution that came to my mind did you consider accessor ?
you can define an accessor in your job model so what it does the needed queries to fetch the data if you are just interested about reading the data and it will be much simpler like so

```php
    // app/Models/Job.php
    public function tasksData(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: function () {
                $tasks = collect();
                foreach ($this->types as $type) {
                    $tasks = $tasks->merge($type->tasks);
                }
                return $tasks->unique('id');
            },
        );
    }
```

and in case you always wants it you can add it to model appends and that case laravel will evaluate it will loading the data

```php
protected $appends = ['tasksData'];
```

Comment: I don't think the given solution will works, because in their case the relationship is between model and model, mine is between pivot_model and model, job_type has many tasks and tasks has many job_type while job_type is a pivot table between jobs and types. But anyway i will try the solution first - thanks for replying.

Comment: it doesn't really matter once you enter the custom domain you can tailor your relation however you want this was just an example but the idea is the same once you define a custom relation you will have full control how the query is constructed and you can make all joins you need to achieve the desired result

Comment: @Luna answer updated to add the custom relation implementation and also I added another solution to use accessor instead of custom relation

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs:            id,  name
jobs_types:  job_id, type_id
types_tasks:         type_id, task_id
tasks:                             id, description

SELECT j.name,
       k.description
    FROM jobs        AS j
    JOIN jobs_types  AS jy   ON jy.job_id = j.id
    JOIN types_tasks AS yk   ON yk.type_id = jy.type_id
    JOIN tasks       AS k    ON k.id = yk.task_id
    WHERE j.name = "XYZ"
```

Note:  There is no need for `id` in the many-to-many tables, but there is a need for indexes like:

```
jobs_types:
    PRIMARY KEY(job_id, type_id)
    INDEX(type_id, job_id)
```

(I do not know how to translate that into Laravel.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but in case anyone else is wondering, you could create a method utilizing [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries) in your `Job::class` model, and then call as method, not as property. So, `Job::find(1)->jobTasks()`.

The query builder might look something like this:

```
namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Job extends Model
{
    public function jobTasks($id): Collection
    {
        return DB::('tasks')
            ->join('job_type_task', 'job_type_task.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id'),
            ->join('job_type', 'job_type_task.job_type_id', '=', 'job_type.id')
            ->join('jobs', 'job_type.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
            ->join('types', 'job_type.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
            ->select('jobs.*', 'types.name as type_name', 'tasks.description')
            ->where('jobs.id', $id)
            ->get();
    }
}
```

And then call it as method as mentioned above but pass an `$id` as an argument.

This won't create an Eloquent Relationship, but it will get you the information you're looking for while utilizing your `Job::class` model. Relationships can be built in your database for cascading or restricted updates and deletes.

At this point, you can do anything you want with the information. Loop, or map through it and get individual fields as necessary...

`Job::find(1)->jobTasks(1)->map(fn($jobTask) => [$jobTask->name => $jobTask->type_name]);`